# Git action copy git repository folder to google cloud

Tags: git, gcloud, github-actions

I am trying to copy my WordPress theme folder to the google cloud ubuntu server using git actions on push. Most of the documentation I found is on docker and my requirement is fairly simple i.e.

For example in my git repository when I make changes the folder "wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme" needs to be copied to ubuntu google cloud server folder "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme"

The closest help I came across is [gcloud action](https://github.com/actions-hub/gcloud) but it doesn't explain where and how to specify the commands (like `rsync` or `cp`) in the yaml file

Comment: "but it doesn't explain where and how to specify the commands (like rsync or cp) in the yaml file" - the "usage" part at the top of the README specifically gives a `gsutil` example using the `cp` command.

Comment: @JonSkeet gsutil is for cloud storage bucket, in my case I am using computer engine ubuntu server (not the cloud storage)
I tried the same format on gcloud it errored as `ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'cp'`

Comment: So what `gcloud` command *are* you trying to execute? `gcloud` doesn't have commands of `rsync` or `cp`? Are you sure you want to be using `gcloud` at all? It's not clear why you expected that to be what you need.

Comment: It's possible that you really want scp: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to automate the WordPress deployment using GitHub Actions which involve briefly following steps

- Establishing an SSH connection between GitHub and google cloud Ubuntu virtual instance
- Configuring the GitHub Actions with YAML file

This involves several different steps documented in my blog post [GitHub actions to deploy WordPress on google cloud](https://jeminpro.com/github-actions-to-deploy-wordpress-on-google-cloud/)